# Php não serve para aplicações em tempo real?

Tags: php

Andei pesquisando e tudo que encontro é NodeJs, socket.io e entre outros, mas nada relacionado às funções nativas de socket do php. Por que isso ocorre? Não tem como fazer algo como um chat usando apenas javascript e php sockets?

Estou querendo estudar essas funções, mas do que adiantará se elas não tiverem serventia, ou não atenderem ao que quero fazer (chat, principalmente)? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, dá pra usar PHP para fazer aplicações tempo real, você pode usar a http://socketo.me/ que é biblioteca PHP para tal função. Entretanto, o PHP não é uma linguagem amigável com esse tipo de plataforma, o ideal mesmo é usar Node.JS por ser uma linguagem **orientada a eventos** e aí está a diferença entre php e node.js para tais aplicações, é a orientação. Orientação a eventos é melhor que a objetos para real time, na minha opinião.